# How to read an INI file in ruby

Tags: ruby, configuration

How do I read/write an ini file in ruby.  I have an ini file that I need to

1. read
2. change an entry
3. write out to a different location

How would I do that in ruby?  The documentation on this is bleak.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently used [ruby-inifile](http://rubygems.org/gems/inifile). Maybe it's overkill compared to the simple snippets here...

Comment: it's not overkill if it's the simplest way.  I tend to think that a gem designed to handle this specifically would be better.  Don't suppose you could post an example?

Comment: Sure, like this, using Linux .desktop files : http://pastie.org/410612

I don't know if it's a gem though.

Answer (score 15):

### Use the InIFile Gem

As @method said, use the [inifile](http://rubygems.org/gems/inifile) gem. There is also an [ini](http://rubygems.org/gems/ini) gem but I haven't used it.

I found the [documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/i/inifile-2.0.1/IniFile.html) a slightly more helpful than the [documentation here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ini/0.1.1/frames) which is where the gem page links to.

There were not many examples so here is a bit of code to get you started:

### Example Setup

First, create a file `/tmp/desktop.ini` with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Foo Viewer
Comment=The best viewer for Foo objects available!
TryExec=fooview
Exec=fooview %F
Icon=fooview
```

Make sure you have run `gem install inifile` from the command line.

### Example Code

Create a file like `/tmp/ini-test.rb` with these contents:

```
require 'inifile'
require 'pp'

# read an existing file
file = IniFile.load('/tmp/desktop.ini')
data = file["Desktop Entry"]

#output one property
puts "here is one property:"
puts data["Name"]

# pretty print object
puts "here is the loaded file:"
pp file

# create a new ini file object
new_file = IniFile.new

# set properties
new_file["Desktop Entry"] = {
    "Type" => "Application",
    "Name" => 'test',
    "Exec" => 'command',
}

# pretty print object
puts "here is a object created with new:"
pp new_file

# set file path
new_file.filename = "/tmp/new_ini_file.ini"

# save file
new_file.write()
puts "the new object has been saved as a file to /tmp/new_ini_file.ini"
```

### Example Results

Running that file with `ruby /tmp/ini-test.rb` should yield something like:

```
here is one property:
Foo Viewer

here is the loaded file:
{ this output hidden for brevity }

here is a object created with new:
#<IniFile:0x007feeec000770
 @comment=";#",
 @content=nil,
 @default="global",
 @encoding=nil,
 @escape=true,
 @filename=nil,
 @ini=
  {"Desktop Entry"=>
    {"Type"=>"Application",
     "Name"=>"test",
     "Exec"=>"command",
     "Icon"=>"icon_filename",
     "Comment"=>"comment"}},
 @param="=">

the new object has been saved as a file to /tmp/new_ini_file.ini
```

Modify as required suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the module for reading and writing of .ini-files with as less change to original file as possible (for files which read humans and machines):

`class IniFileExc < RuntimeError
end`

class IniNode
  def initialize(name, value=nil)
    @line_start = -1;
    @line_end = -1;
    @level = 0;
    @name = name;
    @value = value;
    @keys = {};
    @keylist = [];
    @modified = false;
    @deleted = false;
  end
  attr_reader :level,:line_start,:line_end,:name,:value,:keylist,:keys,:modified,:deleted
  attr_writer :level,:line_start,:line_end,:name,:value,:keylist,:keys,:modified,:deleted

def to_str
    return @name.to_s + ' = ' + @value.to_s;
  end

def to_s
    return @value.to_s;
  end
  def to_i
    return @value.to_i
  end
  def to_f
    return @value.to_f;
  end

def 
    insert(key, nil);
    return @keys[key];
  end

def insert(key, value)
    return false  if (@keys.has_key?(key));
    node = nil;
    if (value && ((value.class == IniNode) || (value.class == IniSection)))
      node = value;
    else
      if (@level <= 0)
        node = IniSection.new(key);
      else
        node = IniNode.new(key, value)
      end
    end
    node.line_start = @line_end + 1  if (node.line_start < 0);
    node.level = @level + 1;
    @keys[key] = node;
    @keylist.push(key);
    return true;
  end

def []=(key, value)
    rc = insert(key, value);
    @keys[key].value = value;
    @keys[key].modified = true;
    @modified = true;
  end

def delete(key)
    return false  if (! @keys.has_key?(key));
    @keys[key].deleted = true;
    @modified = true;
  end
end

class IniSection < IniNode
  def initialize(name)
    super(name);
  end

def to_str
    return  ('[' + @name + ']');
  end
end

`class IniFile < IniNode
  def initialize(path, load=true)
    super(path);
    @lines = [];
    reload()  if (load);
  end`

def reload
    begin
      input = File.new(@name, "r");
    rescue
      raise;
    else
      prevnode = node = self;
      lineno = 0;
      input.each do |line|
        @lines.push(line);
        parsed_node = parse_line(lineno, line);
        if (parsed_node);
          if (parsed_node.class == IniSection)
            if (parsed_node != node)
              prev_node = node;
              node = parsed_node;
              insert(node.name, node);
              prev_node.line_end = lineno - 1;
            end
          else
            node.insert(parsed_node.name, parsed_node);
          end
        end
        lineno += 1;
      end
      input.close;

```
  node.line_end = @line_end = lineno - 1;
end
```

end

def parse_line(lineno, line)
    return nil  if (line =~ /^\s*$/);
    return nil  if (line =~ /^\s*#/);
    return nil  if (line =~ /^\s*;/);
    if (line =~ /^\s*[\s*(.+)\s*].*$/)
      rv = IniSection.new($1);
      rv.line_start = lineno;
      rv.level = @level + 1;
      return rv;
    elsif (line =~ /^\s*(\S?.*[^=\s])\s*=\s*(\S?[^#;]*[^#;\s\n]).*$/)
      rv = IniNode.new($1, $2);
      rv.line_start = rv.line_end = lineno;
      rv.level = @level + 2;
      return rv;
    end
    return nil;
  end

def write
    inserted = {};
    @keylist.each do |sect|
      sectnode = @keys[sect];
      next  if (!sectnode.modified || sectnode.deleted);
      if (sectnode.line_end < 0)
        @lines.push("\n");
        @lines.push(sectnode.to_str + "\n");
      end
      sectnode.keylist.each do |key|
        keynode = sectnode.keys[key];
        next  if (!keynode.modified || keynode.deleted);
        if (keynode.line_end < 0)
          if (sectnode.line_end < 0)
            @lines.push(keynode.to_str + "\n");
          else
            idx = sectnode.line_end.to_i;
            inserted[idx] = []  if (! inserted.has_key?(idx));
            inserted[idx].push(keynode.to_str);
          end
        else
          line = @lines[keynode.line_start];
          if (line =~ /^(\s*)(\S?.*[^=\s]\s*=\s*\S?.+[^#;\s])(\s*[#;].*)$/)
            line = $1 + keynode.to_str + $3 + "\n";
          else
            line = line.gsub(/^(\s*)(\S?.*[^=\s]\s*=\s*\S?[^#;]+[^#;\n\s])(.*)$/){
              $1 + keynode.to_str + $3};
          end
          @lines[keynode.line_start] = line;
        end
      end
    end

`deleted = {};
    @keylist.each do |sect|
      sectnode = @keys[sect];
      next  if (!sectnode.deleted && !sectnode.modified);
      if (sectnode.deleted && (sectnode.line_start >= 0) && (sectnode.line_end >= 0) \
          && (sectnode.line_end >= sectnode.line_start))
        for i in sectnode.line_start..sectnode.line_end
          deleted[i] = true;
        end
      end
      sectnode.keylist.each do |key|
        keynode = sectnode.keys[key];
        next  if (!keynode.deleted);
        deleted[keynode.line_start.to_i] = true  \
          if ((keynode.line_start >= 0) && (keynode.line_end >= 0) && (keynode.line_start == keynode.line_end));
      end
    end`

```
begin
  file = File.new(@name, 'w');
rescue
  raise(IniFileExc, "Failed to open " + @name + " for writing: #{$!}", caller);
else
  cnt = -1;
  @lines.each do |line|
    cnt += 1;
    if (inserted.has_key?(cnt))
      inserted[cnt].each do |ins|
        file.puts(ins + "\n");
      end
    end
    next  if (deleted[cnt]);
    file.puts(line);
  end
  file.close;
end
```

end
end

Usage example:

```
begin
  ini = IniFile.new('file.ini');
  ini['common']['param'] = 'value';
  ini['common'].delete('unused_param');
  ini.delete('unused_section');
  print "Valuable value: ", ini['common']['param'], "\n";
  ini.write;
rescue IniFileExc
  print "Oh, that's not good: ", $!, "\n";
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this code looked appealing, but I could not copy/paste the snippet successfully into an file and run it. any way to correct?

Comment: I've split the code to several pieces - looks like there's a bug in site engine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:
http://rubygems.org/gems/ini

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

```
outFile = File.new('out.ini', 'w')
File.open('in.ini', 'r') do |inFile|
  inFile.each_line do |line|
    # foo is the entry you want to change, baz is its new value.
    outFile.puts(line.sub(/foo=(.*)/, 'foo=baz'))
  end
end
outFile.close
```

Note that when you use `File.open` with a block, the file will automatically be closed when the block terminates.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and tried using the `inifile`, `ini` gem also mentioned here, it's just an old version of it, not compatible with Ruby >= 1.9.
I ran into some issues: inifile 3.0.0 [can't read quoted values](https://github.com/TwP/inifile/issues/39), 2.0.2 can but [breaks](https://gist.github.com/uvlad7/0048d65d288dfe71ee1bb60fcc587e3a#file-test_inifile-desktop-L6) them, also it can't read list values separated by `;` and only saves the first part - I guess it considers them as comments, but I also don't want the comments to be removed - and adds extra spaces and empty lines.

So I decided that the standard GLib [KeyFile](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.KeyFile.html) reader is the most reliable solution and used this [binding](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/blob/master/glib2/README.md). You can see the whole script and the results comparison [here](https://gist.github.com/uvlad7/0048d65d288dfe71ee1bb60fcc587e3a#file-sync_jetbrains-rb), but it basically does this

```
require 'glib2'

file1 = GLib::KeyFile.new
file1.load_from_file(filename1)
file2 = GLib::KeyFile.new
# you can also use file2.load_from_data(File.read(filename2))
file2.load_from_file(filename2)
file1.set_string(group, key, file2.get_string(group, key))
# the binding doesn't expose save_to_file, so we have no choise
File.open(filename2, "w") do |out|
  out.write file1.to_data
end
```

You can also see an example [here](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome/blob/master/glib2/sample/keyfile.rb). The only unexpected change I noticed was the addition of a newline at the end of the file.

I also found `iniparse` [gem](https://github.com/antw/iniparse), it works well in my case and the result is the same, but I still find GLib more reliable. I'm going to create an `inifile-glib` gem with the same API as `inifile` and I'll update the answer if I do.

Answer (score -4):

```
file = File.new("your.ini", "r")
  while (line = file.gets)
   puts "#{line}" #additionally make changes
  end
file.close
```

Comment: Can't make changes on a file that's opened with "r" - should be "r+"

Comment: That's why I am outputting to console -- I don't like reading and writing the same file in one go (and some exercise for the OP) :)

Comment: very simple I'm looking for a more abstract way addressing the keys and values not only line by line.  something like x=INIfile.new('iniin.ini');x['section','key']='newvalue';x.write("newinifile.txtx")
something like this seems more straightforward since I know that i'm working with an in file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. File != 'an ini file'.