# Sed Issues in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sed

I'm trying to update a site generator at work. One of the things that must be done is editing the gitosis.conf file to add the repo to the right group. This is how that block is currently set up in my gitosis.conf file.

```
[group sites]
writable = site1 site2 site3 randomsite awesomeness
members = @devs
```

So after countless tries, I've made a few "advancements" and then some steps back.

```
sed -i"" -e"/sites/,\$s/writable.*/& PROJECTNAME/" gitosis.conf
```

I was finally able to get the code to work on the CentOS command line, but now if I try to run it in irb (running it in a ruby script with backticks, so this has to work) I get this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: `&'
>   => ""

"char 22" may be incorrect because I've edited some of the words a little bit to make the example more vanilla.

This is what is actually in the ruby script.

```
gitosis = `sed -i"" -e"/sites/,\$s/writable.*/& PROJECTNAME/" gitosis.conf`
```

I've been searching everywhere to try to fix this, but so far I've come up with nothing. I've read various places that a better option is ruby -pe in order to keep it ruby, but I don't even know where to start with that. Any advice/input would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: I'm kind of confused why you don't do it all in Ruby?

Comment: I had just already done something similar but in bash, so I was trying to just transpose my old script into the existing site generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't really need to escape the `$` variable. Try using this -

gitosis = `sed -i"" -e "/70/,/$/s/75/& #{p}/" gitosis.conf`

OR

gitosis = `sed -i"" -e "/70/,$ s/75/& #{p}/" gitosis.conf`

*Though I am not too sure what are you planning to do with the variable that you are assigning this `sed one-liner` to. Since it is an `in-line substitution`, you will get a variable with nothing in it.*

Comment: It works, but as is the code adds the text before the equal (writable PROJECTNAME = ...). I fixed it though! I wasn't planning on doing anything with the variable, just doing it to keep things straight for myself. Thank you!

Comment: Oh ok. Yea coz the variable won't have anything. But I wasn't sure if you were planning to use the variable as a test condition to do some follow up actions if the variable was null. But I'm glad everything worked out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it with `sed`, if you can't do it other way, you can always go without `&` like:

```
gitosis = `sed -i"" -e"/plexus/,\$s/\(writable.*\)/\1 #{projectname}/" gitosis.conf`
```

But with `ruby` you can [parse](http://eric.lubow.org/2009/ruby/parsing-ini-files-with-ruby/) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478470/11621) [write](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4918) `.ini` files and your ruby script will work without `sed`!

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, written on the fly, but should get you started toward using a pure-Ruby solution:

```
# [group sites]
# writable = site1 site2 site3 randomsite awesomeness
# members = @devs

FILENAME = 'gitosis.conf'

# bail if the group is missing from the command line
abort('Missing group to add') if (ARGV.empty?)

# read the file
contents = File.read(FILENAME)

# find and extract the "writable" line
writable = contents[/^writable.+$/]

# open the new file. This will automagically close it when done.
File.open("#{FILENAME}.new", 'w') do |fo|
  # output the current file, replacing the current writable line with one containing the old
  # contents with the added new group followed by a line-ending.
  fo.print contents.sub(writable, writable + ' ' + ARGV.shift + "\n")
end

# add code here to handle moving/deleting/something with the old file and
# moving the new file into place.
```

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot. I'll let you know what the result is!